# Changing value of a NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I am having problems changing the value of an NSString.

It is declared in my class like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableString *votes;
```

When the object is created, it is set like this:

```
song.votes = [dict objectForKey:@"Votes"];
```

And finally is where the trouble occurs.  Later in my code I try to modify the value like this:

```
song.votes =[responseArr valueForKey:@"CNT"];
```

This line is leading to this crash:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setVotes]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f84430'

I'm think my problems is caused by one of these:
1. Incorrectly setting the properties above.  I've tried setting it as `(copy, nonatomic)` as well but it does the same thing.
2. i need to use an NSMutableString for this.  I tried changing it to NSMutableString but it still crashes when it changes (admittedly I am initializing and changing it the way way when using NSMutableString, am not entirely sure how to change things when its Mutable.

Comment: What is the message given when the crash occurs?

Comment: @Tommy - Sorry, updated original post with message

Comment: The error message states that `song` itself is a string. Is there any way that could be happening?

Comment: Yes you are right...according to the debugger that is happening somehow, am currently investigating.  How could you tell from that message?

Comment: You can tell from that message because it tells you precisely that -- you did a call that looks like `[__NSCFString setVotes]`.  "__NSCFString" is the internal class name of NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you're allocating / setting your `song` object. Somewhere between setting the first and the second value, you're probably deallocating `song` and then trying to set it's properties, or you're modifying it in such a way that it's not the same class type anymore.

`unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f84430'` pretty much sums it up for you. The second time you try to set the `votes` property, it tries to access the synthesized setter (`setVotes`) from `song` which is no longer the class you think it is.

From the error it looks like you may be re-allocating `song` as a NSString object. That's why it's trying to access a `setVotes` method on `NSString` and such a method does not exist, so it bails out and crashes.
Are you sure you're not doing something like `song = [someString retain];` ?

Comment: My function searches for a song and returns it...somewhere down the line it wasn't returning the song so it was nil all along....its always the small things!

Answer (score 1):

Use `-mutableCopy` if you need a mutable copy of your `NSString`.

```
song.votes = [[dict objectForKey:@"Votes"] mutableCopy];
```

Assuming `responseArr` is an array, `[responseArr valueForKey:@"CNT"]` returns an array with the return value of each of the instances in `responseArr`. Your property is for a `NSMutableString`, but you set it to a `NSArray`.

(Also, do provide the actual error that you get when you crash instead of just saying 'it crashes'.)